# Discrete set with a finite set of limit points?

Tags: general-topology

I am confused by an exercise where my instructor considers $M$ to be a compact connected manifold of dimension at least $2$ and then he takes a subset $A\subseteq M$ that is discrete and has a finite set of limit points.

I don't understand the last part about $A$ having a finite set of limit points. How can a discrete set have any limit points at all since it is made up of isolated points? To me this assumption seems superfluous, but I would be happy to see a counterexample if there exists one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, the set $\{\frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is discrete and has a finite set of limit points, which is $\{0\}$.

Here limit points of $A$ refer to limit points in the ambient space $M$. While points of $A$ will never be limit points (in fact, $A' = \overline{A}\setminus A$), there can exist points outside of $A$ that are limit points of $A$ (in $M$).

Comment: thank you! Just a question: you mean that $A'=\overline{A}\setminus A$ since $A$ is discrete, right? This is not true in general.

Comment: Yes, $\overline{A} = A'\cup A$, and since $A$ is discrete, $A'$ and $A$ are disjoint. And if $A'$ and $A$ are disjoint, then in fact, $A$ is discrete, so $A' = \overline{A}\setminus A$ is *equivalent* to $A$ being discrete.